# CSS menu dropdown alignment not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I have been asked to look at this site http://www.edowa.org.au/ but can't find the problem.

The second level menu items are aligned correctly in IE10.0.5 and FF35.0.1 but not in Chrome (latest version). In Chrome the second level menu items are pushed to the right.

Here is the CSS

```
    /* MAIN NAVIGATION - TABS
----------------------------------------- */
#nav {
        clear:both;
        width: 900px;
        height: 29px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding:5px 20px 0 20px;
    }
        #nav ul {
            width: 900px;
            display: inline-table;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #nav li {
            list-style: none;
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        *:first-child+html #nav li {
            float: left;
        }
        *html #nav li {
            float: left;
        }
        #nav li a {
            border: 0;
            display: block;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 29px;
            color: #59523f;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        *:first-child+html #nav li a {
            padding:0 33px;
        }
        #nav li a.current,
        #nav li a:hover {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background: url(../images/li-bg-hover.jpg) repeat-x;
        }

        /*_________second level menu__________*/
        #nav li ul { 
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 20;
            width: 175px;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            left: -999em;
        }
        #nav li ul li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 175px;
            min-height: 31px;
            display:block;
        }
        #nav li:hover ul, 
        #nav li li:hover ul, 
        #nav li.sfhover ul, 
        #nav li li.sfhover ul { 
            left: auto;
        }
        *:first-child+html #nav li:hover, 
        *:first-child+html #nav li li:hover, 
        *:first-child+html #nav li.sfhover, 
        *:first-child+html #nav li li.sfhover { 
            left: auto;
            position: static;
        }
        #nav li ul li a {
            padding: 0 10px;
            display: block;
            width: 175px !important;
            line-height: 31px;
            height:auto;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: left;
            color:#d6d4af;
            background: url(../images/li-li-bg.png) repeat-x;
        }
        #nav li ul li a:hover {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background: url(../images/li-li-bg-hover.png) repeat-x;
        }
```

Here is the html

```
<div id="nav">
            <ul>


    <li><a href="/" class="current" >Home</a></li>



    <li><a href="/meet-the-edo/" class="link" >Who We Are</a></li>



    <li><a href="/services/" class="link" >What We Do</a>
    <ul>

        <li><a href="/services/legal-advice-2/" >Legal Advice</a></li>

    </ul>
    </li>



    <li><a href="/discover/" class="link" >Discover</a>
    <ul>

        <li><a href="/discover/publications/" >Publications</a></li>

        <li><a href="/discover/factsheets/" >Factsheets</a></li>

        <li><a href="/discover/newsletters/" >Newsletters</a></li>

        <li><a href="/discover/archive/" >Archive</a></li>

        <li><a href="/discover/e-bulletins/" >E-Bulletins</a></li>

        <li><a href="/discover/community-legal-education/" >Community Legal Education</a></li>

    </ul>
    </li>



    <li><a href="/participate/" class="link" >Participate</a>
    <ul>

        <li><a href="/participate/join/" >Join</a></li>

        <li><a href="/participate/donate/" >Donate</a></li>

        <li><a href="/participate/volunteer/" >Volunteer</a></li>

        <li><a href="/participate/jobs/" >Jobs</a></li>

    </ul>
    </li>



    <li><a href="/links/" class="link" >Links</a></li>



    <li><a href="/contact/" class="link" >Contact</a></li>
```

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `li` `left: auto;` to `left: 0;` and add `position: relative;` to  `#nav li`. Like this:

```
#nav li {
            list-style: none;
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            position: relative; /*Added*/
        }

#nav li:hover ul, 
        #nav li li:hover ul, 
        #nav li.sfhover ul, 
        #nav li li.sfhover ul { 
            left: 0; /*Added*/
        }
```

[**I've created a fiddle here (added colors for testing purposes).**](http://jsfiddle.net/fjtas0ck/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#nav{
  float : right;
  /* or float = left */
}
```

Comment: you have to add this cod in your class or id and you can change it push them to left or right

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a little mess within absolute positioning and "auto" value.

Please, try changing the following:

```
#nav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative; /* new line */
}
#nav li:hover ul, 
#nav li li:hover ul, 
#nav li.sfhover ul, 
#nav li li.sfhover ul { 
    left: 0; /* changed value */
}
```

It should do it on all major browsers.